# Windows Universal App - Visual Assets

Tags: icons, win-universal-app

I am completely bewildered by the Visual Assets tab in the `package.appmanifest`.
It complains about everything.

Could someone give an idiots guide to the minimum png's you are meant to create, what you are meant to call them, and where you put them, and how you load them into the Visual Assets Tab?

I get most icons using the Asset Generator at the top. It complained about the size of the 1240x1240 in the Large Tile, but deleting the actual png in the output directory seemed to stop that red cross appearing. (Note it requires an extraordinary act of divine fortune to get any 1240x1240 png file below MS's max file size. So why put it in?)

Unfortunately the Generator does not create the Splash Screen. After trial and error, I found **just** (note just) putting in a 1240x600 png in the 200 box appears to resolve the errors on that one. (Putting other sizes in the other boxes appears to confuse Visual Studio.)

The other you must fill in is the PackageLogo. This complains about everything you try. If you put in the 50x50 it complains the 200 is not there. If you create one of those it complains you have both a 200 and 50. If you remove the 50 it complains about that.

Then, after all that, any file you have referenced but removed during the whole process will produce an error when you rebuild your project, even though it is not being used any more.

Please help, I am tearing my hair out.

Comment: Have you read the document of the [Guidelines for tile and icon assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-app-assets#asset-types). The easiest way to provide more versions of the assets is to leverage a Visual Studio extension called [UWP Tile Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shenchauhan.UWPTileGenerator).

Comment: Which version of Visual are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 2017 as IDE. I suggest you to use the `Assets Generator` (which is inside the `Package.appxmanifest` with the following assets

> Small Time, Medium Tile, Wide Tile, Large Tile, App Icon, Splash Screen

`Badge Logo and Package Logo` are not necessary unless you have notification to care about.

If you want to do it by yourself, these are the minimum recommended :

- Small Tile : Scale 400%, 200%, 100%
- Medium Tile : Scale 400%, 200%, 100%
- Wide Tile : Scale 400%, 200%, 100%
- Large Tile : Scale 400%, 200%, 100%
- App Icon : Scale 400%, 200%, 100%, 24px
- Splash Screnn : Scale 400%, 200%, 100%

> Finally. If you are using Visual Sudio Assets Generator, please pay attention to the following. It generates assets correctly but sometimes I got stuck for store submission because there was a `StoreLogo.png` file in my Assets folder that should be removed.